# Socket exchange between winsock & QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I found this socket code with winsock2.h http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/12/c-winsock-example-using-client-server.html This a code for my client.

```
int hsock;
int * p_int ;
hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
///

char buffer[1024];
int buffer_len = 1024;
int bytecount;

int c;
memset(buffer, '\0', buffer_len);

for(char* p=buffer ; (c=getch())!=13 ; p++){
    printf("%c", c);
    *p = c;
}

if( (bytecount=send(hsock, buffer, strlen(buffer),0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
```

code for server is done with Qt QTcpServer Class:

```
void FortuneThread::run()
   {
   QTcpSocket tcpSocket;
   if (!tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
       emit error(tcpSocket.error());
       cout<<"socket error"<<endl;
       return;
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
    strcat(buffer, " SERVER ECHO");

    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    out << &socketDescriptor;
    out << buffer;
    out << strlen(buffer);
    out << 0;

    tcpSocket.write(block);
```

Above server code is my failed attempt to match the server data with the client data. What is wrong? ty

Comment: What, precisely, isn't working? Is it not connecting? Is the client receiving different data than it expects?

Comment: Yes, the last thing : Error receiving data 10053.

Comment: Are you sure, that connection is established correctly? BTW in snippet you have provided, both server and client are sending, none of them is receiving.

Comment: yes i did not include this bit from client :if((bytecount = recv(hsock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))==SOCKET_ERROR){

Comment: To make it clear I am using code from above link and http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-threadedfortuneserver.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Qt sockets so can't contribute much on the server side code. However, I'm assuming that since it came from the samples it ought to be correct.

Your client code, OTOH, does not make a connection to the server. For a TCP socket you need to

1. create the socket - you're doing this
2. connect to a peer socket using connect() - *this is missing*
3. send the data using send() - you're doing this too

Watch out for how you specify the port numbers. If you're on Windows, it uses little endian while network byte order is in big endian. Sockets library provides htons() and ntohs() to convert between the two. Make sure that the port number you pass to connect() (through the sockaddr_in* argument) is of the same byte order as what is used to create the Qt server. This is relevant for IP address as well, but less of an issue as one typically uses the inet_addr("xx.xx.xx.xx") to convert a string to IPv4 DWORD in the correct byte order.

Lastly, note that you may not receive everything you send in one read() at the server. Servers have to do buffering until a end-of-message marker is encountered (or preset length of message is read).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works: (messy)

```
void FortuneThread::run()
{

QTcpSocket tcpSocket;
if (!tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
    emit error(tcpSocket.error());
    cout<<"socket error"<<endl;
    return;
}
//in part
tcpSocket.waitForReadyRead(10000);
int joj = tcpSocket.bytesAvailable();
char inbuffer[1024];
tcpSocket.read(inbuffer,1024);
string instring;
instring = inbuffer;
instring.resize(joj);
cout<<instring<<endl;

//out part
char buffer[1024];
int buffer_len = 1024;
int bytecount;

memset(buffer, '\0', buffer_len);


string outstring = "hey client!";
    int TempNumOne=outstring.size();

    for (int a=0;a<TempNumOne;a++)
    {
        buffer[a]=outstring[a];
    }

QByteArray block;
block = buffer;


tcpSocket.write(block);
tcpSocket.disconnectFromHost();
tcpSocket.waitForDisconnected();
}
```